# Button changes location on smaller screen - how to centre it instead of "margin-left: 0"?

Tags: css, wordpress, breakpoints

Website: https://bucksfoodpartnership.org/

So on my desktop the text over the top image "**Buckinghamshire Food Partnership believe that everyone is entitled to a Right to Food**" and the button "**Get involved**" are aligned to left with 10% margin. However on smaller screen the text is centered (as it should be), but the button is aligned to the far left. How can I make it centered as well (not all the time, only when the text above is centered)?

I think this class makes it aligned to left:

```
.content-caption {
    max-width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
```

but adding

```
position: relative; 
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

or

```
margin: auto;
```

Doesn't help really. Am I barking at the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set `wp-block-button` to `width:100%`.

```
.wp-block-button{
 width:100%;
}
```

Because of all the inherited styles and the way `inline-block` behaves with `text-align:center` this will work for you. Even across your breakpoints.

Comment: you're a champ! thank you very much